# Simple color flooding game in Javascript/HTML5 canvas area

Tags: javascript, game, canvas

I'm learining JS. I have prepared a simple color flooding game, like [*Pixelated*](http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-game-quick-look-pixelated).

The engine below works, though scoring is not implemented.  Please help me find out how this code could be made better, more idiomatic JavaScript, or more efficient.

```js
// global variables
var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var colors = ["#FF7F34", "#FF4D79", "#FFEF42", "#78E853", "#64C4FF", "#954FFF"];
var squareSize = 20;
var canvasSize = 14;
var buttonSize = 30;
var spaceSize = 15;
var board = [];
var currentColor = 0;

// draw 14x14 board of randomly coloured squares and add each square to 2d array 'board'
function drawBoard(colors) {
    // draw main board
    for (var i = 0; i < canvasSize; i++) {
        var boardColumn = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < canvasSize; j++) {
            colorId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6)) + 1;
            context.fillStyle = colors[colorId - 1];   
            context.fillRect(i*squareSize, j*squareSize, squareSize, squareSize);
             if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                currentColor = colorId;
                colorId = 0;
            }
            boardColumn.push(colorId);
        }
        board.push(boardColumn);
    }    
    // draw controls
    colors.forEach(function (value, i) {
        context.fillStyle = value;
        context.fillRect(i * (buttonSize + spaceSize) + spaceSize, squareSize * canvasSize + spaceSize, buttonSize, buttonSize);
    });
    expandOcean(currentColor);
    redrawBoard();
}
// click handler
function clickToColor(event) {
  var color = 0;
  var x = event.x;
  var y = event.y;
  x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
  y -= canvas.offsetTop;
  var controlsOffsetTop = squareSize * canvasSize + spaceSize; 
  colors.forEach(function(value, i) {
    if (x > (spaceSize + i * (spaceSize + buttonSize)) && x <= ((i + 1) * (spaceSize + buttonSize)) && y > controlsOffsetTop && y <= (controlsOffsetTop + buttonSize)) color = i + 1;
  });
    if (color != 0 && color != currentColor) 
        {
            currentColor = color;
            expandOcean(currentColor);
            redrawBoard();
        }
}
// flooding with chosen color
function expandOcean(color) {
    var touched = false;
    board.forEach(function(column, i) {
        column.forEach(function(value, j) {
            if (j + 1 < canvasSize && ((column[j] == 0 && column[j+1] == color) || (column[j] == color && column[j+1] == 0))) {
                board[i][j+1] = 0;
                board[i][j] = 0;
                touched = true;
            }
        });
    });
    board.forEach(function(column, i) {
        column.forEach(function(value, j) {
            if (i + 1 < canvasSize && ((column[j] == 0 && board[i + 1][j] == color) || (column[j] == color && board[i+1][j] == 0))) {
                board[i + 1][j] = 0;
                board[i][j] = 0;
                touched = true;
            }
        });
    });
    if (touched == true) expandOcean(color);
}

function redrawBoard() {
    board.forEach(function(column, i) {
        column.forEach(function(value, j) {
            if (board[i][j] == 0) {
                context.fillStyle = colors[currentColor - 1];
            } else {
                context.fillStyle = colors[board[i][j] - 1];
            }
            context.fillRect(i*squareSize, j*squareSize, squareSize, squareSize);
        }); 
    }); 
}

drawBoard(colors);
canvas.addEventListener('click', clickToColor, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <canvas id="game" width="280" height="400"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The board is just a grid. Have you considered _not_ using a `<canvas>`?

Comment: I haven't considered it, but you are right - simple table would do as well. I just wanted to write this game in JS, and the mechanism would stay the same, only output interface would be different.

Answer (score 1):

This would be so much easier with the use of a table or divs. You could then create an array of objects (one object per square). Ex:

```
[
    {
        "className": "orange",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
    }
];
```

By doing this, you can match the class of the surrounding objects, rather than changing the color directly. Hope this helps.

Comment: Make sure to match "className" to a css class.